# Time is returning incorrect format

Tags: javascript

The time is returning incorrect format. I would like to return time in `HH:MM` format. The below code work doesn't work when the time has got zero in it, for example 14:00 14:03 and 14:10  returns in the following format 14:0, 14:3 or 14:1. Please shed some idea to resolve this.

```
function getTime() {
var time = new Date();
time.setHours(time.getHours()+1);
return time.getHours() +':'+time.getMinutes();
}

const getcurrTime = getTime();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.getHours()` and `.getMinutes()` will always return an integer. You need to pad the integer:

```js
 function getTime() {
   var time = new Date();
   time.setHours(time.getHours()+1);
   return time.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') +':'+time.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

const getcurrTime = getTime();
console.log(getcurrTime);
```

For readability, I would most likely write:

```js
function getTime() {
  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(time.getHours() + 1);

  var hours = time.getHours()
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, '0');
  var minutes = time.getMinutes()
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, '0');

  return hours + ":" + minutes;
}

var currentTime = getTime();

console.log(currentTime);
```

Comment: Readability is a matter of preference, I think long chained calls are bad as they make debugging more difficult. `('0' + time.getHours()).slice(-2)` is a lot less to type. *getHours* and *getMinutes* do not always return an integer, they may return *NaN*. ;-)